# How do I log SQL statements in Vapor 3/Fluent?

Tags: postgresql, vapor

It looks like in Vapor 2 you could do something like:

```
let query = <some fluent query object>
logger?.debug(query)
```

and it would print out the full SQL statement, but I'm not seeing any documentation of how to do that now in Vapor 3.

How can I see what SQL is being generated by my `QueryBuilder`?

Comment: Isn't this: https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/database-kit/overview/ a starting point? Check the final paragraphs of the Config section.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! Was able to find it in that doc – kept looking in all the wrong places, so thank you for pointing it out :) Added an answer, but would be happy to give you credit if you post one!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but you've done all the work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Nick in the comments, who pointed me to the right set of docs. This can be accomplished by using the `enableLogging` method. So now my configure.swift includes this code:

```
let dbConfig: PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig
if let url = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL"), let psqlConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(url: url, transport: .unverifiedTLS) {
    dbConfig = psqlConfig
} else {
    dbConfig = ...something for the local db...
}

let postgresql = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: dbConfig)

/// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.enableLogging(on: .psql)
databases.add(database: postgresql, as: .psql)
services.register(databases)
```

The important line being the third from the bottom. For a while I was trying to enable debugging on `PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig`, so to anyone in the future, take note that you're enabling it on the `DatabasesConfig` object instead.